# How to add exchange rates into a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make  a shiny currency exchange app in R. This is what i have done so far:
**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
            headerPanel("European Exchange Rates"),
            sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("variable", "Change:",
                                    list("EUR" = "European Euro",
                                         "ATS" = "Austrian Schilling",
                                         "DEM" = "German Mark",
                                         "ESP" = "Spanish Peseta",
                                         "FIM" = "Finnish Markka",
                                         "FRF" = "French Franc",
                                         "IEP" = "Irish Pound",
                                         "ITL" = "Italian Lira",
                                         "LUF" = "Luxembourgian Franc",
                                         "NLG" = "Dutch Guilder",
                                         "PTE" = "Portuguese escudo",
                                         "BEF" = "Belgian Franc",
                                         "CYP" = "Cypriot Pound",
                                         "EEK" = "Estonian Kroon",
                                         "GRD" = "Greek Drachma",
                                         "SIT" = "Slovenian Tolar")),
                        selectInput("variable2", "To:",
                                    list("EUR" = "European Euro",
                                         "ATS" = "Austrian Schilling",
                                         "DEM" = "German Mark",
                                         "ESP" = "Spanish Peseta",
                                         "FIM" = "Finnish Markka",
                                         "FRF" = "French Franc",
                                         "IEP" = "Irish Pound",
                                         "ITL" = "Italian Lira",
                                         "LUF" = "Luxembourgian Franc",
                                         "NLG" = "Dutch Guilder",
                                         "PTE" = "Portuguese escudo",
                                         "BEF" = "Belgian Franc",
                                         "CYP" = "Cypriot Pound",
                                         "EEK" = "Estonian Kroon",
                                         "GRD" = "Greek Drachma",
                                         "SIT" = "Slovenian Tolar"))
            ),
            mainPanel(
                        h3('Exchanged Currency'),
                        h4("From"),
                        verbatimTextOutput("oid1"),
                        h4("To"),
                        verbatimTextOutput("oid2"),
                        h4("Amount"),
                        verbatimTextOutput("amount")

            )
))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(
            function(input, output) {
                        output$oid1 <- renderPrint({input$variable})
                        output$oid2 <- renderPrint({input$variable2})
                        output$amount <- renderPrint({input$amount})
            }
)
```

I assume I have to add the exchange rates in the `ui.R`, with `numericInput` but i just don't know how to set the combinations with the currencies. I have the rates taken from the R dataset `euro.cross`. I would appreciate some indications on how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the `euro.cross` data set slightly adding a `EUR` row to it and a `EUR` column:

Define some globals:

```
tempcross <- rbind.data.frame(euro, euro.cross)
tempcross$EUR <- c(1, 1/euro)
row.names(tempcross)[1] <- "EUR"
currencies <- list("EUR" = "European Euro",
     "ATS" = "Austrian Schilling",
     "DEM" = "German Mark",
     "ESP" = "Spanish Peseta",
     "FIM" = "Finnish Markka",
     "FRF" = "French Franc",
     "IEP" = "Irish Pound",
     "ITL" = "Italian Lira",
     "LUF" = "Luxembourgian Franc",
     "NLG" = "Dutch Guilder",
     "PTE" = "Portuguese escudo",
     "BEF" = "Belgian Franc",
     "CYP" = "Cypriot Pound",
     "EEK" = "Estonian Kroon",
     "GRD" = "Greek Drachma",
     "SIT" = "Slovenian Tolar")
```

run the app

```
runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("European Exchange Rates"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("variable", "Change:", currencies),
      selectInput("variable2", "To:", currencies)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3('Exchanged Currency'),
      h4("From"),
      verbatimTextOutput("oid1"),
      h4("To"),
      verbatimTextOutput("oid2"),
      h4("Amount"),
      verbatimTextOutput("amount")

    )
  )

  , server = function(input, output) {
    output$oid1 <- renderPrint({input$variable})
    output$oid2 <- renderPrint({input$variable2})
    output$amount <- renderPrint({
      curr1 <- names(currencies[currencies %in% input$variable])
      curr2 <- names(currencies[currencies %in% input$variable2])
      tempcross[curr1, curr2]
    })
  }
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking of something like a "box" were you insert the amount you would like to exchange, but this will work as well. Thank you.

Comment: @alecsx if this answers your question please consider marking it answered by pressing the tick